# Error in model frame variable lengths differ in | R

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, panel-data, economics

I have a data set like this:

```
  PiS_a <- Panel[, c("Rok","Powiat","Liczba bezrobotnych", "Srednie_wynagrodzenie", "Prawo i Sprawiedliwość")]
    
    PiS <- na.omit(PiS_a)
    
    PiS_05_07 <- subset(PiS, Rok %in% c(2005,2007))
```

I define the variables for my fixed_effects_model:

```
  Indeksy <- pdata.frame(PiS, index = c("Rok","Powiat"))
    
    explained_variable <- PiS_05_07$`Prawo i Sprawiedliwosc`
    
    explanatory_variables <- c(Logarytm_bezrobotni,Logarytm_srednie_wynagrodzenie)
```

The lenght of these variables are different:

```
 > length(explained_variable)
    [1] 741
    > length(explanatory_variables)
    [1] 1482
```

And probably that is why the result of my model is an error:

```
> fixed_effects_model <- plm(explained_variable ~ explanatory_variables, data = Indeksy, effect = "twoways", model = "within" )
Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'explanatory_variables')
```

Is there a way to change the length of explanatory_variables? I tried to create a seperate data set for explanatory_variables but it did not work. I tried something like this:

```
> fixed_effects_model <- plm(explained_variable ~ Logarytm_bezrobotni + Logarytm_srednie_wynagrodzenie, data = cbind(Indeksy, explanatory_variables), effect = "twoways", model = "within" )
```

Thank you very much for your help!